If $\log_7 5$ = a , $\log_5 3$ = b , $\log_3 2$ = c, then the logarithm of the number 70 to the base 225 is?
So, I've tried using the properties:
$$\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$$
and..
$$\log_a bc = \log_a b + \log_a c$$
And, the final simplification should be in the following options:
$$A. \frac{1-a+abc}{2a(1+b)}$$ $$B. \frac{1-a-abc}{2a(1+b)}$$ $$C. \frac{1+a-abc}{2a(1+b)}$$ $$D. \frac{1+a+abc}{2a(1+b)}$$
I also tried substituting values in the options but it takes eternity to finish.... 
Plz help....

Your change of base formula is incorrect. The correct formula is $\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$.

Ohh! srry , Lemme correct it lol

So we could rewrite and create new logarithm terms with respect to a,b and c. In the question we need $$\log_{225} 70 .$$  Here 225 can be written as 3x3x5x5. Amd 70 can be written as 2×5×7.
Now we get $$\frac{\log_2 2 + \log_2 5 +\log_2 7}{2(\log_2 3 + \log_2 5 )}$$
Now we can rewrite this as $$\frac{1+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{abc}}{2(\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{bc})}$$
After taking LCM we get
$$\frac{1+abc+a}{2a(1+b)}$$
Hope this clears your doubt.

$$\begin{align*}
\log_{225}70&=\log_{225}(2\times 5\times 7)=\log_{225}2+\log_{225}5+\log_{225}7\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\log_2 225}+\dfrac{1}{\log_5 225}+\dfrac{1}{\log_7 225}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\log_2 3+2\log_2 5}+\dfrac{1}{2\log_5 3+2}+\dfrac{1}{2\log_7 3+2\log_7 5}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2/c+2/bc}+\dfrac{1}{2+2b}+\dfrac{1}{2ab+2a}\\
&=\dfrac{1+a+abc}{2a(b+1)}
\end{align*}$$

I think, numerator is not correct.

As an alternative way, using exponential, we have that

$\log_7 5 = a \iff 7^a=5$
$\log_5 3 = b \iff 5^b=3$
$\log_3 2 = c\iff 3^c=2$

then
$$\log_{225}70 =x \iff 225^x=70 \iff (3^2\cdot 5^2)^x=(2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7)\iff 3^{2x\left(1+\frac1b\right)}=3^{c+\frac1b+\frac1{ab}}$$
therefore
$$x= \frac{c+\frac1b+\frac1{ab}}{2+\frac2b}=\frac{1+a+abc}{2a+2ab}$$

I was going to post something similar - if confused about logs and the base change formula it is always possible to go to powers.

Yes indeed this is a nice alternative! Thanks, Bye

By the change of base formula, the given logarithms are equivalent to:
$$a = \frac{\ln 5}{\ln 7} \implies \ln 5 = a \ln 7 \tag{1}$$
$$b = \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 5} \implies \ln 3 = b \ln 5 \tag{2}$$
$$c = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3} \implies \ln 2 = c \ln 3 \tag{3}$$
Substituting (1) into (2), we get:
$$\ln 3 = ab \ln 7 \tag{4}$$
Substituting (2) into (3), we get:
$$\ln 2 = bc \ln 5 \tag{5}$$
And substituting (1) into (5) gives:
$$\ln 2 = abc \ln 7\tag{6}$$
So we can now write the three other logarithms in terms of $\ln 7$:
$$\ln 2 = abc \ln 7$$
$$\ln 3 = ab \ln 7$$
$$\ln 5 = a\ln 7$$
We are asked to find:
$$\log_{225} 70$$
$$=\frac{\ln 70}{\ln 225}$$
$$=\frac{\ln (2 \times 5 \times 7)}{\ln (3^2 \times 5^2)}$$
$$=\frac{\ln 2 + \ln 5 + \ln 7}{2\ln 3 + 2\ln 5}$$
$$=\frac{abc \ln 7 + a\ln 7 + \ln 7}{2ab \ln 7 + 2a\ln 7}$$
$$=\frac{abc + a + 1}{2ab + 2a}$$
$$=\frac{1 + a + abc}{2a(1 + b)}$$
Aka answer choice (D).

$$S=
\log_{225}70=\frac{\ln70}{\ln225}=\frac{\ln2+\ln5+\ln7}{2(\ln3+\ln5)}
$$
$$\log_53=b\implies \ln3=b\ln5$$
$$\log_32=c\implies\ln2=c\ln3=bc\ln5$$
$$\log_75=a\implies\ln7=\frac1a\ln5$$
So,
$$S=\frac{bc+1+\frac1a}{2(b+1)}=\frac{1+a+abc}{2a(1+b)}$$
D
